# android-can't get value of edit text in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

I've tried get edittext value but does not work.This is my code in android fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_patient, container, false);
    final EditText FirstName=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
    final Button addPatientButton=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.AddPatientButton);
    addPatientButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isOnline()) {
                try {
                    if (FirstName.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                        FirstName.setError("First Name is required!");
                        return;
                    }
```

I receive error at this line :`FirstName.getText().toString().trim().equals("")`

The error is following: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference`.

Here is my fragment_add_patient xml file which contains all items.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ionut.myapplication.PatientController.AddPatientFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/PatientFirstName"
    android:hint="First Name" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:id="@+id/PatientLastName"
    android:hint="Last Name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/PatientFirstName"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PatientFirstName"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/PatientFirstName" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/PatientLastName"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/PatientLastName"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/PatientLastName"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/Email"
    android:hint="Email" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:id="@+id/PatientAge"
    android:hint="Age"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Email"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Email"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Email" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/PatientAge"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PatientAge"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/PatientAge"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/PatientPhone"
    android:hint="Phone" />


<Button
    android:text="Add Patient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/AddPatientButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="77dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/cspinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/PatientPhone"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/PatientPhone"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/PatientPhone"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PatientPhone"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/PatientPhone" />
```

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: FirstName is null

Comment: Please post fragment_add_patient.xml. Be sure it has an EditText with id FirstName.

Comment: i post fragment_add_patient

Comment: the edittext id is "PatientFirstName" in xml, but in your code u use "FirstName" change code to "PatientFirstName".

Comment: There is no `EditText` with ID `FirstName`

Comment: Yes ! That is the problem.I used 'FirstName' in another activity.Thanks all !.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FirstName EditText is null because the findViewById method is trying to find an editext with the id of `FirstName` but the correct id is `PatientFirstName`

To solve the issue, replace the

```
final EditText FirstName=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
```

with

```
final EditText FirstName=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.PatientFirstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you are trying to query of non existing id in your layout .

the actual id for your "First Name" EditText is "PatientFirstName". also try to make your code just a little bit organized as follows

1- Declare your Button , EditText variables as a global variable to be accessible anywhere inside your fragment

2- if you gonna add more buttons with click events then you should make your fragment or activity implements the View.onClickListener

Comment: I assume by "global" you mean "field". Local variables are okay. And anonymous inner classes are fine for OnClickListeners.